# I need some software to remove some malwares such as mapcar.exe and picexa.exe

Tags: malware, antivirus, malware-detection, trojan, antimalware

I tried searching online for soft wares for these functions and came up with unhackme and hitman pro. But then i did more research on both of these soft wares but came up inconclusive about their ability. Are these two programs useful or should i use another program to remove the malware? If so, what are the programs you recommend.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score -1):

Any reputable antivirus software would work well for you. I personally reccomend [Comodo Internet Security](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjxxJy015DQAhWK6CYKHXucBTAQFggpMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.comodo.com%2Fhome%2Finternet-security%2Fsecurity-software.php&usg=AFQjCNHvP6q7hli88i9CLkx793XRtmT7mA&sig2=gFFmJyUb0dOowdlljA_V4Q&bvm=bv.137904068,d.eWE).